# CodeIgniter | Move index.php to public folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm new to CodeIgniter and thought could give it a try by

1. Downloaded the code thats available in CodeIgniter
2. Changed the base url to `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8000';`
3. Started the server using command `php -S 0.0.0.0:3000`

This went pretty well .Next I tried to move the `index.php` file to a public folder- and thats when things started breaking.

1. Moved index.php to a newly created public folder
2. Created a new file public/.htaccess with the below code snippet

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
   RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
   RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$  ./index.php/$1 [L]
   ```
3. Modified `$system_path = '../system';` and `$application_folder = '../application'`; in `public/index.php`.
4. I get a `404 Resource not found`, when I try to access the page after restarting the server.

Comment: Try not to move index.php ,keep system ,application and assets folder inside one folder and add your files inside application /controller,application/models and application/views

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the root folder in the server configuration?

If you moved index.php to a different folder, you should have changed the path to index.php in the server settings. In the configuration file.

Comment: I’m using php -S 0.0.0.0:3000 to turn on the server . Where should I make the path configuration change ?

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty simple

```
$system_path = __DIR__ . '../system';
$application_folder = __DIR__ . '../application';
```

and use the normal codeignitor .htacess file and everything runs fine.
Symfony does the same in index.php.
Of course your css, image, upload folders should be inside the public folder.
then you can remove all index.html files and

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

statements ;)